# gnuplot and "Failed to initialize wxWidgets"

Tags: gnuplot

i want to plot120 files with gnuplot.

```
plot '18205.plot' u 1:3 w l t '18205' , '18208.plot' u 1:3 w l t '18208'
Failed to initialize wxWidgets.
         warning: Warning - difficulty fitting plot titles into key
         warning: Too many axis ticks requested (>1e+01)
         warning: Too many axis ticks requested (>1e+01)
         warning: Too many axis ticks requested (>6)
```

the files looking like

```
21      4       0.865671
22      4       0.894175
23      4       0.921895
24      4       0.949053
25      4       0.975792
26      4       1.00147
27      4       1.02577
28      4       1.05008
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The important bit is this:

```
Failed to initialize wxWidgets.
```

This means that gnuplot couldn't open a window to plot using wxWidgets.
Be sure that the terminal where you are running gnuplot can open windows in X. You can do that by typing `echo $DISPLAY` in the terminal (or `!echo $DISPLAY` from within gnuplot) and checking if it's not empty and if it makes sense (usually this means a value of `:0.0`. If it should be anything different, you should know that because you have set it up that way ;) ).

Setting the right X permissions is also necessary if you are running gnuplot as a different user (or on a different host e.g. via ssh) than the one running the graphic environment. in a secure environment `xhost +` would do, but if you are on a network and specially not behind a firewall, `xhost server-running-gnuplot.domain` would be a much wiser choice.

Comment: If I write that command in the console, it doesn't give me back anything, I guess then the terminal does not have permissions to open windows X. How can I give it permissions to do it?

Answer (score 5):

*Apparently* this is it failing to detect a terminal it likes.  On my Debian stable "gnuplot 4.4 patchlevel 0" I get an identical error until I add some:

`set terminal png`

...at which point it works fine.  Raaage!

Answer (score 3):

I was getting the same errors.  However, I realised that I did not have X permissions in my current terminal window.  This would explain why switching terminal formats to non-X (ie. jpg/png) worked for the guys above as well.

Answer (score 2):

As the warning suggest you probably have too many keys in you plot. Try leaving away the titles and `set key off`.
Also you might want to take a look at iterations like in [THIS](http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.com/2010/01/plot-iterations-and-pseudo-files.html) blog at the bottom. This would clean up your script quite a lot.
You might want to ask yourself if you really want to plot 120 lines in a singe plot!?

Answer (score 1):

just set area size, such as:

```
set terminal png size 1500 1200
```

and then plot

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error. Switching to a different output format fixed it for me.

To have your graph be a jpg:
    set term jpeg

To see all possible output formats:
    help term